# Why is the ngrx Store is being directly updated by changing arrays inside components?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

My problem is as follows,

I am subscribing to my store via the following code

```
export class PrioritySelectComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input('preset') preset: number; 

  prioritySettingSub: Subscription
  priorities: string[]

  selection: number;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<fromApp.AppState>
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void{
    this.prioritySettingSub = this.store.select('projectState').subscribe(data => {
      this.priorities = data.prioritySettings
    })
    if(this.preset !== undefined) {
      this.selection = this.preset
    }
  }

  arrayTest() {
    const potato = '4'
    let newArr = this.priorities
    newArr.push(potato);
  } // this updates the store immediately when run 


  ngOnDestroy(): void{
    this.prioritySettingSub.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Priority Settings is an array that is housed in my store that contains 4 strings
'none', 'low, 'medium', 'high'.

I am making a copy of the array inside my store subscription and using that inside the component. But if I update the copy (priorities), without using a dispatch the store gets instantly updated.

For testing reasons the arrayTest() function is hooked up to a button in the html that fires it on a click event. When clicked '4' gets added to the store array instantly.

This is the project store:

```
export interface ProjectState {
    projects?: Project[];
    prioritySettings: string[];
    addProjectError: boolean
}

const initialProjectState = {
  projects: [],
  prioritySettings: ['None', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High'],
  addProjectError: false
};

//reducer logic...
```

this is the html template

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Priority" [(ngModel)]="selection">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let level of priorities, let i = index" [value]="i">{{level}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<button (click)='arrayTest()' >terst</button>
```

This does not happen when I do the exact same thing with objects, strings, or numbers

An example of a this method that doesn't break is as follows

Component:

```
export class TextInputComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


  textsub: Subscription
  textValue: string;

  constructor(
    private store: Store.fromApp<AppState>;
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.textsub = this.store.select('textinput').subscribe(data => {
      this.textValue = data.textValue
    })
    this.textValue = this.presetValue;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.textsub.unsubscribe()
  }

  stringtest(){
    const potato = '4'
    let test = this.textValue
    test = potato;
  }

}
```

html:

```
<mat-form-field >
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="textValue" name="textValue" >
</mat-form-field>

<button (click)='stringtest()' ></button>
```

When stringtest() is fired the store does not update, and won't unless a dispatch is set up.

This issues with arrays happens in multiple places in my application, I choose this one for its simplicity. In each case it is arrays that cause the problem, why is this the case and how can I fix this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you "making a copy of the array" in your component? I don't see you making a copy anywhere. I see you pointing a new variable to the array here `let newArr = this.priorities` but that is not copying the array.

Comment: ngOnInit(): void{
    this.prioritySettingSub = **this.store.select('projectState').subscribe(data => {
      this.priorities = data.prioritySettings**
    }) I set the array inside subscription in ngOnInit

Comment: That isn't making a copy. That is pointing your `priorities` property to the same memory location that the `data.prioritySettings` is pointing to.

Comment: Then why does it work for strings? and how would I copy it?

Comment: Please read up on OO programming concepts of passing by value and reference and all of that kind of stuff.

Comment: If you are using external libraries like lodash, please use ._cloneDeep to make copies of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a copy of an array instead of holding onto the original reference (which is why you are having problems), you can use `slice()` to make a copy:

```js
this.priorities = data.prioritySettings.slice(0);
```

Your `priorities` will now have a new array with all of the same contents. The contents of the array will still have the same references though so if you have an object in there and modify it, you will still be modifying the one in your store.

Comment: How can I create a true copy when I need to? That will clone the objects as well?

Comment: Since it seems like you are newer to programming, I would recommend using a library like lodash to help you out with this stuff to make sure it gets done correctly. They have a deep clone method that will take care of all of this. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#cloneDeep